# Is it possible to optimize mysql query with datatime field difference?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with a DATETIME field called `date_created`, and need to check for some data with this kind of query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created) + $number < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Is it possible to do this without the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function? Maybe with NOW())?
And if it is, will it be faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > Is it possible to do this without the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function? Maybe with NOW())?

   Not exactly.  Whilst you could do the following, it won't achieve the exact same results:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date_created + INTERVAL $number SECOND < NOW()
   ```

   The reason is that, unlike `TIMESTAMP`, `DATETIME` is neither intended nor capable of representing a specific instance in time; rather, it effectively represents the display of a calendar/clock (not the same thing).

   When using the above query, which does not go via a UTC timestamp, the comparison is merely a question of whether a clock right now would show a date/time later than that which was recorded in the database (plus `$number` seconds).

   However, when converting to a UTC timestamp, the timezone of the respective clock displays become relevant and because many timezones are not constant (e.g. they often move around for daylight savings), multiple `DATETIME` values could give rise to the same UTC timestamp.

   For example:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE `table` (date_created DATETIME);
   INSERT INTO  `table` VALUES ('2012-10-28 01:00:00'), ('2012-10-28 02:00:00');
   ```

   Then compare the results of the two queries when run at `2012-10-28 02:00:00` in the UK:

   - Your original query:

     ```
     SET SESSION time_zone = 'Europe/London';

     SELECT *
     FROM   `table`
     WHERE  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_created) + 100
          < UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2012-10-28 02:00:00');
     ```
   - The alternative query above:

     ```
     SELECT *
     FROM   `table`
     WHERE   date_created + INTERVAL 100 SECOND
           < '2012-10-28 02:00:00';
     ```
2. > And if it is, will it be faster?

   Probably (a lexicographic order for the comparison will suffice, versus parsing & converting the `DATETIME` values to UTC according the session timezone's rules followed by subtraction and sign inspection), but I'd advise performing your own benchmarks.

Comment: Since performing operations on every value prevents the use of indexes, you could mathematically move the operation to the other side of the expression, where it would only have to be calculated once then compared against the untouched index values. `date_created < '2012-10-28 02:00:00' - INTERVAL 100 SECOND` As far as I'm aware, MySQL won't automatically make that optimization, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Using eval expression in WHERE clause should be avoided if possible. It prevents correct utilization of indexes. If possible do the math in code and send the values as query parameters.